# How to do a range bar graph in matplotlib?

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I'm trying to make a plot using matplotlib that resembles the following:

[image: Desired sort of image]

However, I'm not quite sure which type of graph to use. My data has the following form, where start x position is a positive value greater or equal to 0:

```
<item 1><start x position><end x position>
<item 2><start x position><end x position>
```

Looking at the docs, I see that there is [barh](http://matplotlib.org/examples/lines_bars_and_markers/barh_demo.html) and [errorbar](http://matplotlib.org/examples/statistics/errorbar_demo_features.html), but I'm not sure if its possible to use barh with a start offset. What would be the best method to use, given my type of data? I'm not that familiar with the library, so I was hoping to get some insight.

Comment: There is [some sort of
consensus](http://www.ncsu.edu/labwrite/res/gh/gh-bargraph.html#rangebar)
on using the term **"Range Bar Graph"** for the type of disposition
that you've asked for, and at the same time thare is no web reference
to a `matplotlib` solution to this problem.

May I ask you to change the title of your question to a more
searchable one? E.g., stemming from your own, "Proper plot to use in
matplotlib for a range bar graph?"  or maybe the more direct "Drawing
a range bar graph using Matplotlib"...

Thank you for the consideration,

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### Appetizer

[image: exactly what you asked for]

### Commented Code

As far as I know, the most direct way to do what you want requires that you directly draw your rectangles on the `matplotlib` canvas using the `patches` module of `matplotlib`

A simple implementation follows

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.patches as patches

def plot_rect(data, delta=0.4):
    """data is a dictionary, {"Label":(low,hi), ... }
    return a drawing that you can manipulate, show, save etc"""

    yspan = len(data)
    yplaces = [.5+i for i in range(yspan)]
    ylabels = sorted(data.keys())

    fig = plt.figure()
    ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
    ax.set_yticks(yplaces)
    ax.set_yticklabels(ylabels)
    ax.set_ylim((0,yspan))

    # later we'll need the min and max in the union of intervals
    low, hi =  data[ylabels[0]]
    for pos, label in zip(yplaces,ylabels):
        start, end = data[label]
        ax.add_patch(patches.Rectangle((start,pos-delta/2.0),end-start,delta))
        if start<low : low=start
        if end>hi : hi=end

    # little small trick, draw an invisible line so that the x axis
    # limits are automatically adjusted...
    ax.plot((low,hi),(0,0))

    # now get the limits as automatically computed
    xmin, xmax = ax.get_xlim()
    # and use them to draw the hlines in your example
    ax.hlines(range(1,yspan),xmin,xmax)
    # the vlines are simply the x grid lines
    ax.grid(axis='x')
    # eventually return what we have done
    return ax

# this is the main script, note that we have imported pyplot as plt

# the data, inspired by your example, 
data = {'A':(1901,1921),
        'B':(1917,1935),
        'C':(1929,1948),
        'D':(1943,1963),
        'E':(1957,1983),
        'F':(1975,1991),
        'G':(1989,2007)}

# call the function and give its result a name
ax = plot_rect(data)
# so that we can further manipulate it using the `axes` methods, e.g.
ax.set_xlabel('Whatever')
# finally save or show what we have
plt.show()
```

The result of our sufferings has been shown in the first paragraph of this post...

### Addendum

Let's say that you feel that blue is a very dull color...

The `patches` you've placed in your drawing are accessible as a property (aptly named `patches`...) of the drawing and modifiable too, e.g.,

```
ax = plot_rect(data)
ax.set_xlabel('Whatever')
for rect in ax.patches:
    rect.set(facecolor=(0.9,0.9,0.2,1.0), # a tuple, RGBA
          edgecolor=(0.6,0.2,0.3,1.0),
          linewidth=3.0)
plt.show()
```

[image: NO. MORE. DULLNESS.]

In my VH opinion, a custom plotting function should do the least indispensable to characterize the plot, as this kind of post-production is usually very easy in `matplotlib`.

Comment: Thanks! This helped my tremendously :)